# Why doesn't [obj selectorNotDefined] cause a warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want that something like this:

```
[myObject selectorNotDefined];
```

will cause a warning. Is there an option to make this happen?

To be more specific, when I add this code to my existing project:

```
NSObject *myObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[myObject selectorNotDefined];
```

The compiler will not invoke any warning.

If I create a new project and add these lines it invokes a warning.

What's wrong with my existing project?

Comment: Please be more specific with what you want. Do you want to be able to pass an undefined message to an object and have it actually do something meaningful with it? Do you just want to get rid of the warning? what?

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting clarifications as answers (which they aren't). This isn't a forum; the idea is for the best answer to bubble up to the top, which would leave conversations all out of order.

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
NSObject *myObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[myObject selectorNotDefined];
```

You will definitely get a warning: myObject might not respond to selector selectorNotDefined

Or you can check:
i

```
f([myObject respondsTo:selector(selectorNotDefined)]{
 [myObject selectorNotDefined]; //or
[myObject performSelector:(selectorNotDefined) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type you have assigned `myObject`. If it's an `id` type, you won't get any warnings, but if you make it a specific object type, the compiler will check to see of the method is declared in the header files.

Comment: Almost;  you will still get warnings for methods that aren't declared anywhere.  The compiler has to see a method declaration to be able to figure out how to encode arguments & return value.